# Search criteria for Lucene Examine

Tags: full-text-search, lucene.net, umbraco

I'm trying to compose a reasonable search mechanism for a website which contains infomation stroed in text articles. I'm doing the search in umbraco lucene's examine.

So, the let's say the fields I'm searching is "bodyText" and "titleText",

What i've come up with for the filter is this:

```
var filter = criteria
           .GroupedOr(new string[] { "bodyText","titleText"}, SearchTerm)
           .Compile();
```

What is an example of a better search, that would include, for example, results which contain the SearchTerm ("literate" will be a result for "iter" search), or any other improvement for that search ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `Fuzzy()`?

From http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/9/16/examining-examine.aspx

> Sometimes users will query your site looking for a term that they could have misspelled or is very close. Fuzzy gives you the ability to get Lucene to look for terms that look like your term.  Eg mound could actually be sound.

```
var query = searchCriteria.Fields("nodeName","hello".Fuzzy(0.8)).Compile();
```

> The optional value you pass into Fuzzy between 0 and 1 specifies how Fuzzy or how close the match is to the original. For instance a match of 0.5 will not return when a threshold of 0.8 is specified.

I'm not quite sure that syntax is right, but play around with that. It may not actually do partial word searches, but could possibly give closer results to what you're looking for.